# Two questions on parametric equations, vectors, and planes.

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

I have two questions regarding parametric equations that I am struggling with.

**Question 1:**

a) Give a parametric equation for the line passing through $(-1,-2,3)$ and $(1,5,-2)$.

b) Give the symmetric equation for the line in part a).

**My work:**

I have found a parametric equation for part a), namely:

$x = -1+2t \\
y = 5+7t \\
z = -2-5t$

I am not sure what the symmetric equation is, or even what a symmetric equation is for that matter.

**Question 2:**

Consider the plane $Q$, defined by the equation $2x-2y+z=15$ and the point $P$ with coordinates $(11,-7,6)$.

a) Find a parametric equation for the line through $P$ normal to $Q$.

b) Where does this normal line through $P$ intersect $Q$?

c) What is the distance from $P$ to $Q$?

**My Work**
I was able to figure out part c) easily, finding that the distance is $7$.  That being said, I'm not sure how to solve parts a) and b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

The symmetric equation of a line is in the form of

$$\frac{x-x_0}{a}=\frac{y-y_0}{b}=\frac{z-z_0}{c}$$

In your case, $\frac{x+1}{2}=t$, what else are equal to $t$? Combine them as above, you will get the symmetric equation.

Question 2:

(a) The parametric equation for a line is $\vec{x}=\vec{P}+\vec{d}t$, where $\vec{P}$ is a point on the line, $\vec{d}$ is a direction vector for the line. In this case, the direction vector for the line is the normal vector for the plane, so $(2,-2,1)$. Can you figure out the rest then?

(b) Once you find the line, it should be easy to find the intersection.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.  Although I'm not sure if I fully understand the process to solve question 2.  So would the equation then be: x = <11,-7,6> + <2,-1,1>t ?  Then we would have: x = 11 + 2t, y = -7 - 2t, z = 6 + t ?  Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: You are right. Probably just a typo here: $\vec{x}=<11,-7,6>+<2,-2,1>t$, since your later equations are right.

Comment: Ok great thank you! And yea that was a typo!